# Kendo Grid loading Slowly

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am Trying to load some grecords in to the kendo grid. If I am getting 10 records it is loading quickly. If I have more than 500 it is taking so much time to load.

Can any one help on this?

Below is my code:

```
$("#gridExistingpartners").kendoGrid({
    columns: [{
        field: "PARTNER_ID",
        title: "#",
        filterable: false,
        width: 85
    },
            {
                field: "NAME",
                title: "Partner Name",
                width: 185

            },
            {
                field: "PARTNER_TYPE",
                title: "Partner Type",
                width: 100
            },
            {
                command: { name:"View",text: "View", click: ViewExistingPartners },
                title: "Edit",
                width: 85
            },
            {
                command: { name:"Add",text: "Add", click: AddExistingPartners },
                title: "Add",
                width: 85
            }],
    height: 250,
    autoBind: true,
    scrollable: true,
    sortable: true,
    serverPaging: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    serverFiltering: true,

    refresh: true,
    filterable: {
        extra: false,
        operators: {
            string: {
                startswith: "Starts with",
                eq: "Is equal to",
                neq: "Is not equal to"
            }
        }
    },
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 5,
        pageSize: 15
    }
});
```

Comment: your code looks wrong , serverPaging,serverSorting and filterable are for the datasource and i dont see a datasource . you will have to do serverPaging to reslove your issue . at first load 15-20 data and when user does paging load the next 15-20 data .

Answer (score 0):

One way to load data without paging and faster is using the **scrollable** option. Thus, the grid rows are loaded when you scroll down.

In grid options use:

> scrollable: { virtual: true }

[Read more here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/virtualization-remote-data)